# Coefficient of LASSO with caret

Tags: r, r-caret, lasso-regression

I ran LASSO algorithm with caret glmnet.
I want to know the coefficients especially so as to know which variable shrinks to 0.

For example, I ran following code.(Since this code may be worthless in terms of statistics, please see it just as sample code)

```
library(tidyverse)
iris = data("iris") %>% as.tibble() %>% select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
Sformula = as.formula(Sepal.Length ~ (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width)^2)
fitControl = trainControl( method = "cv", number = 10)
Fit = train(
     Sformula,
     data = iris,
     method = "glmnet",
     preProcess = c("center","scale"),
     weights = NULL,
     trControl = fitControl,
     tuneLength = 10
)
coef(Fit)
```

However, it just returned `NULL`.

How should I do?

#### complement

I ran `coef(Fit$finalModel)`. It seemed coefficient, but 7×82 matrix. the number of feature variables and intercept is 7. What is the column of this matrix?

```
> coef(Fit$finalModel)
7 x 82 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 82 column names ‘s0’, ‘s1’, ‘s2’ ... ]]
                                                                                                                      
(Intercept)              5.843333 5.84333333 5.8433333 5.8433333 5.8433333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.84333333
Sepal.Width              .        .          .         .         .         .          .          .          .         
Petal.Length             .        .          .         .         .         0.01198642 0.02620089 0.03826789 0.04878216
Petal.Width              .        .          .         .         .         .          .          .          .         
Sepal.Width:Petal.Length .        0.06075376 0.1169792 0.1689475 0.2169243 0.25032859 0.27810921 0.30448688 0.32918552
Sepal.Width:Petal.Width  .        .          .         .         .         .          .          .          .         
Petal.Length:Petal.Width .        .          .         .         .         .          .          .          .         
                                                                                                                         
(Intercept)              5.8433333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.8433333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.84333333 5.84333333
Sepal.Width              .         .          .          .          .         .          .          .          .         
Petal.Length             0.0577385 0.06528163 0.07155311 0.07668659 0.0806087 0.08401776 0.08647254 0.08822959 0.08939423
Petal.Width              .         .          .          .          .         .          .          .          .         
Sepal.Width:Petal.Length 0.3524559 0.37439483 0.39508484 0.41459979 0.4331915 0.45037744 0.46672510 0.48213864 0.49665175
Sepal.Width:Petal.Width  .         .          .          .          .         .          .          .          .         
Petal.Length:Petal.Width .         .          .          .          .         .          .          .          .
```

Comment: Try `coef(Fit$finalModel)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have a puzzle about returned matrix. If you don't mind, please check the complement of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the coefficients returned along your regularization path (for each value of `lambda`, and `alpha` in this case too).

`caret` provides an optimal lambda, stored at `Fit$bestTune$lambda`. You can just use that to extract the optimal coefficients matching that lamba as below:

```
lambda_use <- min(Fit$finalModel$lambda[Fit$finalModel$lambda >= Fit$bestTune$lambda])
position <- which(Fit$finalModel$lambda == lambda_use)
data.frame(coef(Fit$finalModel)[, position])
```

And I'm not sure if this just your simplified example here, but this isn't lasso. You're running elastic net and tuning the `alpha` parameter in addition to `lambda`. You'll need to set the alpha parameter to 1 for lasso. Check out the question below for doing so in `caret`.

[Question on glmnet lasso with caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852738/how-to-apply-lasso-logistic-regression-with-caret-and-glmnet)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked well!  Regarding `alpha`, I forgot using `tuneGrid` in this sample code. Again, I appreciate your kind answer.